# Make Nemo show another name for a folder

Tags: linux-mint, nemo, xdg, xdg-user-dirs

I know about that `xdg-user-dir` stuff that helps make home subdirs in desired language.
My locale is Russian and the system created 'download', 'documents', etc dirs in Russian language, and Nemo shows them as they are.
But that's not cool (not handy when typing in terminal).

I know how I can recreate these dirs with English names, okay. But what I want is: **let real dirs on disk have English names but have Nemo to show them in Russian, like Windows does.**

In Windows (and AFAIK, in KDE too), there are hidden `desktop.ini` files that let override the display name for a folder they are in. Nemo seems not to not work that way.

Is it possible in Cinnamon/Nemo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible in Cinnamon/Nemo?

No. The approach that XDG took seems to be deliberately *not* doing that, so nemo doesn't implement that either.

Feel free to make Russian symlinks, i.e., `ln -s ~/Downloads ~/ска́чивание`; doesn't hide the "real" names, but at least gives you something Russian to click on.